# Kivy TextInput input_type doesn't work on iOS

Tags: python, kivy

I'm expecting to see a keyboard with a different layout when changing the `input_type` of a TextInput. It looks like the `input_type` attribute may have been moved to the `FocusBehavior` class, but I'm not sure how to get it working. Here's what I've tried:

`main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    pass

MainApp().run()
```

`main.kv`

```
GridLayout:
    rows: 1
    TextInput:
        hint_text: "text"
        input_type: "text"
    TextInput
        hint_text: "Number"
        input_type: "number"
```

I've also tried changing the `FocusBehavior.input_type` property by adding these lines in `main.py`:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
FocusBehavior.input_type = "number"
```

Here is an image showing that both `TextInput`s display the same keyboard:
[image]